# Jquery Sortable won't alert "order" on update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

This should be straight forward, however I'm having real trouble alerting the order of my sortable list.

Here is my JQuery code that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#projectItems").sortable({
        update : function(event, ui) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
            alert(order);

        }
    });
});
```

and here is my HTML of my list:

```
<ul id="projectItems">
                    <li id="item1" value="<?php echo $studentChoice1; ?>">(1) <?php echo $title[1]; ?><a href='#message1' onclick='deleteProject(".$studentChoice1.",".$userID.")'><img height=20px width=20px alt='Delete' src='img/delete.png' /></a></li>
                    <li id="item2" value="<?php echo $studentChoice2; ?>">(2) <?php echo $title[2]; ?><a href='#message1' onclick='deleteProject(".$studentChoice2.",".$userID.")'><img height=20px width=20px alt='Delete' src='img/delete.png' /></a></li>
                    <li id="item3" value="<?php echo $studentChoice3; ?>">(3) <?php echo $title[3]; ?><a href='#message1' onclick='deleteProject(".$studentChoice3.",".$userID.")'><img height=20px width=20px alt='Delete' src='img/delete.png' /></a></li>
                    <li id="item4" value="<?php echo $studentChoice4; ?>">(4) <?php echo $title[4]; ?><a href='#message1' onclick='deleteProject(".$studentChoice4.",".$userID.")'><img height=20px width=20px alt='Delete' src='img/delete.png' /></a></li>
                    <li id="item5" value="<?php echo $studentChoice5; ?>">(5) <?php echo $title[5]; ?><a href='#message1' onclick='deleteProject(".$studentChoice5.",".$userID.")'><img height=20px width=20px alt='Delete' src='img/delete.png' /></a></li>
</ul>
```

The list is sortable and works, however when the user is finished sorting items it does not display the alert message at all.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck with this for a few days now and can't seem to find a solution online.

**UPDATE**
The problem seems to be with referencing jQuery

The current version of jQuery I am using is 1.7.1 from google's CDN referenced like below in my script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

however when I changed this to :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it did not work at all!

Also when I try reference like below it says there is a jquery referencing error!

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue as it seems to be working fine for everyone else!
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perfectly working http://jsfiddle.net/aeNke/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine, check here :  http://jsfiddle.net/DHJb7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#projectItems").sortable({
    update : function(event, ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        alert(order);
    }
});
});
```

I think you forgot to include jQuery or jQueryUI library. 
And if you have included them, then check versions of the libraries.

**Recommended version:** 1.9.1 for jQuery and 1.9.2 for jQueryUI

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick response, I think this is my issue. I am referencing jquery like this: <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script> How can i reference the jquery ui in the same way?

Comment: Thanks again for the update. This is still not working for me and now that I have the 1.9.1 version of jquery instead of 1.7.1 the list is no longer sortable! I really lost here at the minute as to why its not working correctly.

Comment: I've added in the link for css, like shown above aswell now and it is still working the same. (Doesn't allow any items to be sortable now)

Comment: Firebug is returning jQuery reference error when I try referencing like you have above? Why would this be happening? It only seems to work now for me with ajax.googleapis/../1.7.1 buts does not work this way with 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUXys/1/) link, its working fine for me.

```
         $("#projectItems").sortable({
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                    alert(order);

                }
          });
```

i hope this will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

IT should work. Add jquery ui and jquery library.
Just to be clear that you need to change the positions 
of the items (by drag/drop) to call your desired function (update).